# Does Azure AD integrate with GCP/GKE to allow SSO?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to use Azure AD to authenticate users to GCP/GKE, is this natively possible (i.e. without using some external service to mimic the Azure AD structure in Google Cloud IAM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine three Google Cloud systems to do this:

1. [Cloud Identity](https://cloud.google.com/identity/solutions/overview) which allows you to have Google accounts for @yourcompany.com, managed by you, without G Suite.
2. [Google Cloud Directory Sync](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/106368) which will sync your Active Directory to Cloud Identity.
3. [SSO](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?) allows the actual log-on to use Active Di

With these together, you can have managed accounts synced from Active Directory, that use your Active Directory to log in. There is a great [write up of this set-up on the gcp blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/using-your-existing-identity-management-system-with-google-cloud-platform) that goes into some more detail.